# Inject html in web component

Tags: dart, dart-webui

My dart web component :

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <!--  some html -->
      <p>{{content}}</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

works fine with simple text, but something, I want to display rich content. So `content` could contains html, like `<div class="blue">hello</div>` or hypertext link. But, I just see full html the output. When I inspect the dom, I see the html content in quotes. I think it's for security, but can I change he behavior ? Or doing otherwise ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<content>` tag.

Your web ui template:

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <!--  some html -->
      <content></content>
   </div>
</template>
```

Then when you use your component you can specify the content to insert:

```html
<x-your-component>
  <div class="blue">hello</div>
</x-your-component>
```

And in some other location:

```html
<x-your-component>
  <a href="#">hello</a>
</x-your-component>
```

You can see an example in the [WebUI article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#composition).

Answer (score 0):

By default, content bound to templates is sanitized, i.e. everything which can be interpreted as HTML is escaped properly.

If you want to avoid this, your `content` variable (or, in general, any expression used for binding), must be [an instance of `SafeHtml`](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/summary.html#templating-features). More info [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/spec.html#binding-in-content).

You can create a `SafeHtml` instance like this:

```java
var content = new SafeHtml.unsafe("<b>This is bold</b>");
```

This is still in flux, so expect the unexpected.